# Parsing data from service to component in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

In my service I make a call:

```
    this.potentialOrganizations(currentNode.id)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log('consoling the org data!!!!!!!  '  + JSON.stringify(data))
        this.potentialOrgData = [];
        this.potentialOrgData = data;
        this._potentialOrgs.onNext(true);
      })
```

The data consoles fine, as you can see, I tried using an observable method but it's not working for some reason!

I may need a new way to be able to call the data, as I said in my components html I have this: although it doesn't work:

```
<ul *ngIf="this.engagementService.potentialOrgData.length > 0">
  <li *ngFor="let org of this.engagementService.potentialOrgData">
     <p class="listedOrgs">{{ org.name }}</p>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

In my component I had this:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
this.engagementService.potentialOrgs$.subscribe(
  (data) => {
    if (data) {
      console.log('are we hitting here inside the potentialORG DATA!??!?!?!!?!?')
      this.potentialOrganizations = this.engagementService.potentialOrgData;
    }
  }
)
this.potentialOrganizations = this.engagementService.potentialOrgData;
  }
```

it doesnt console, even though in my service i have the observable thing set:

```
  private _potentialOrgs = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  public potentialOrgs$ = this._potentialOrgs.asObservable();
```

I was thinking maybe I need to use @input instead? but how to do that properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make this a little more simple here by trying the following. If `potentialOrgData` is set from a subscription in the service which it is, it will stay fresh as subscriptions stay open. You will be able to use the variable in the service directly.

```
public requestedData = [];

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.requestedData = this.engagementService.potentialOrgData;
}
```

In your template.

```
<ul *ngIf="requestedData.length">
  <li *ngFor="let org of requestedData">
    <p class="listedOrgs">{{ org.name }}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Behaviour Subjects and Observable's are very powerful but not always necessary.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried actually, you are right it's not always necessary, the html doesn't show anything though doing this!

Comment: after this.requestedData = this.engagementService.potentialOrgData; can you add 
console.log(this.requestedData); Check its defined and show me the output :)

Comment: It appears something else is wrong, as the nginit isnt being called, il go back a step and find out why, then il update the question so you can update answer :)

Comment: but what you have said is the solution to my problem its just i had another problem, so i can accept it as the right answer

Comment: Yeah I would just make sure that in the service `this.potentialOrganizations(currentNode.id)` <-- this is run before the ngOnInit of the component :)

Comment: Yeah the component isnt actually being called, for some reason!